# Android Admob showing blank RocketFuel ads often

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, admob, adview

I have a working AdMob AdView on top of my opengl game. Its working great but I notice that it keeps showing a particular blank ad. I thought it was a bug on my side but then I noticed that the ad is functioning partially. The ad appears to be a RocketFuel ad according to the provided info button in the top right of the AdView. Clicking within the blank AdView area does nothing unless the info button it hit. The images and code below help explain.

I thought RocketFuel was a separate ad service, is it possible to limit its appearance in Google AdMob using the Filter Settings > Category / Type Settings > Affiliate offers? Or perhaps one of the other categories? I am going to try adding a URL Block for rocketfuel.com under the Ad Filters. However I am unsure if they are serving ads directly from their domain.

Otherwise, is there any way to block, report, or limit these types of ads from being shown through my app? Has anyone had similar problems with such ads?

Here is how I slap the adview on top of my java based OpenGL ES 2 renderer:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    mView = new nopgRenderer(this);

    setContentView(mView);

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.IAB_LEADERBOARD, "<AdMobAdAppID>");
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.addView(adView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    adView.setLayoutParams(params);

    this.addContentView(layout, params);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

}

public static void hideAd(){
    adView.setVisibility(AdView.GONE);
}

public static void showAd(){
    adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
}
```

The app on Google Play:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dmtsource.nopg

Example of a normal ad:
[image]

Example of the blank ad:
[image]

Clicking on the info item in the blank ad:
[image]

Comment: Is your `AdMobAdAppID` an AdMob site ID or a Mediation placement ID? I.e., are you sure the ad is coming from AdMob instead of another network?

Comment: I use my Publisher ID from the app's managment page of my AdMob account.